# Repeat years on x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that I used dplyr to create mean values for some numerical variables. I grouped them by site and by year. I'm now plotting the trendlines in ggplot2, using this code and delta is just a variable for the difference in mean values of interest:

```
ggplot(data=df_byyear, aes(x=Year, y=delta)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Siteid)) +geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

The problem I am hitting is that it is adding duplicate years on the x axis as seen in this chart:

[image: chart results from ggplot2 showing the duplicate years]

I've verified the data only contains single instances of each of the three years of interest (please note I've left out the Siteid, each grouping of three years is assigned to one of the different sites.

[image: capture of data - delta column is not shown]

I hope this provides sufficient information to help with this, I've never seen this occur and am still a beginner in r....thanks!

Comment: in your picture the site is missing. You used to group your Data. So the only the combination of Site+Year should be unique, not the year. Can you please provide a example dataset using dput so the 'error ' is reproducable

Comment: Yes, color corresponds to the site. In this case each Siteid has 3 years of unique data (2016, 2017, and 2018)

Comment: Is it possible that the Year column is char or factor rather than numeric?

Comment: Great question, just verified it is a numeric

Comment: so yeah, a `dput` of the data would be helpful to investigate this.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens if you add `scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(df_byyear$Year),labels=unique(df_byyear$Year))` to the gg call? While we're at it - what does unique(df_byyear$Year) give you?

Comment: df_byyear unique values output in r is: 2016, 2017, and 2018. Adding the scale_x_continuous and labels=unique fixed the problem!

Comment: It seems like the graph was plotting additional non-integer points on the axis. What I don't understand is why it wasn't listing them as 2016.5 etc., and also how come 2017 had only one instance. Anyway, happy to hear it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so it's easy for people to find, here's the answer:

It would seem ggplot is adding points along what it considers to be a continuous scale (i.e., 2016.5, 2017.5 etc). I'm not sure why they appear as integers, nor why 2017 only shows up once. At any rate, the way to resolves this is to add the following to the ggplot call:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(df_byyear$Year))
```

This tells ggplot to only place ticks for the numbers that actually appear in df_byyear$Year (that is, the integers).